# How Can I Acces Network Shared Folder in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm getting an image from a folder on the server, like this;

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"\\192.168.0.12\Folder\image.jpg");
```

This is an .net core 3.1 application. When I run this on my computer it works fine, I am getting the image. But when ı release this application and run it on the IIS, I am getting this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: \\192.168.0.12\Folder\image.jpg
```

But definitely there is an image in this path. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, maybe it's a duplicate from :
https://serverfault.com/questions/799385/iis-not-able-to-access-shared-network-folder

Check your network permissions

Comment: Folder needs to be network shared.

Comment: Folder is already network shared. I can access in file explorer when I wrote the path. Problem is not there. And I check the folders permissions, there is all access from everyone.

Comment: "When I run this on my computer it works fine", the program runs under your account. "when ı release this application and run it on the IIS", the program runs under the application pool identity. If this is your first time to play with IIS, learn all key differences that can bite you, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: How did you set application pool identity and network shared folder permission? Are you sure that application pool identity can login in server `192.168.0.12`?

Comment: @BruceZhang I check the application pool identity and it can't login the server that is why application can't found the file in the local server. I change the identity, from ApplicationPoolIdentity to a custom identity who access the local server. Thanks for the correct guidance.

Comment: You can post the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application pool in IIS, I change the identity, from ApplicationPoolIdentity to a custom identity who can access the local server. Then the application, accessed the folders I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that your local network is different from the server on which the application is published.

Depending on where the server is located, the firewall must be enabled.
With `ipconfig` in the command shell you can find out your own IP address and the default gateway.

Therefore it is necessary to find out the remote server IP address and adjust the firewall (open ports).

Comment: 192.168.0.12 is local IP address still.

Comment: No, my local network is in the same server with my applications publish server. I am publishing this application on the local server.